Public transit travel planner for Zadar, Croatia?
I'm looking for a travel planner, as in something giving you a route suggestion from point A to point B.
I've looked everywhere online, but I'm not sure if it exists?
Maybe the Zadar Smart City app has it? I can't seem to sign up for it without a Croatian phone number though.
I did find bus schedules on the municipal website, but they don't seem to say when the bus stops at individual stops. Only from the first stop. Also, I'm having a hard time locating the locations of the stops on a map. A travel planner would be a lot more convenient.

Liburnija is the main transport operator, they have a very nice website mentioning the routes with timings. They provide city transport, suburban transport and transport on the islands. This helpful link might give you some more useful info regarding transporation in Zadar.

I found that website using Google, But as I discussed in OP, it doesn't seem to have a travel planner. I also mentioned some of the other shortcomings of the route schedules posted there.

Openstreetmap shows the routes and stops, but does not seem able to provide directions using public transport.

@jcaron Oh, awesome.

In southern european countries, particularly Italy, it isn't uncommon for departure times to be specified publicly only for the first stop of each run

@FDMS Even in Germany I have seen similar things, but then there’s usually an indication of the travel time from the departure point to each of the stops.
